# I want to Upload Multiple Files with PDF/Doc/Docx/txt format in blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: zend-framework, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload with PHP Zend framework.
I have setup plugin successfully but now I want the plugin should allow PDF, doc , docx and txt file formate to be upload.

Is there any constant setting in any file?

Is there any way to find documentation for blueimp jquery file upload.

Please let me now the way to allow for file format.

Answer (score 0):

See the section in

[How to restrict the file selection dialog to show only specific file types?](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-restrict-the-file-selection-dialog-to-show-only-specific-file-types)
It shows how to restrict the file types.

Pete

Comment: Thank you Pete for reply.

This is pretty helpful, by using this I can restrict user to select particular files.
 
But I want to validate it on server side and client side as well.
If any other format (except PDF files) file get uploaded then need to validate the script.

need to only allow PDF files by client and severer side.

Comment: The sample PHP code already checks the file extensions at around line 100 of the UploadHandler.php source code. This must be just about what you need.

Comment: Below is the actual line of code :
'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',

Now I am putting this :
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(pdf|doc|docx)$/i',

It is working for me?
but is it correct technically?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `acceptedFileTypes`

```
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(pdf|doc?x|txt)$/i,
```

Code would looks like

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                autoUpload: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                content: {image: 'fff'},
                headers: headers.headers,
                disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                maxFileSize: 5000000,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(pdf|doc?x|txt)$/i,

            });
```